# Bedeutung von chennet?

Tags: meaning

Im Theaterstück [*Lassalle fragt Herrn Herbert nach Sonja*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lassalle_fragt_Herrn_Herbert_nach_Sonja) von Christoph Hein wird ein paar Mal das Wort "chennet" benutzt. Zum Beispiel:

- Friedland zu Lassalle's Mutter:

  > Und wenn ich Ihrem Sohn die Rente beschneide, weil das faules Geld ist, was nach Berlin geht, und nichts einbringt dem Geschäft, will ich, daß Sie **chennet** bleiben und nicht sticheln und nicht hetzen.
- Friedland zu Lasalle:

  > Machen wirs **chennet** aus, Schwager. Ich zahl dir die Gasrente noch für sechs Jahre. Bleibt dir die jährlich Revenue.
- Friedland zu Herbert (Friedland will, dass Herbert Lassalles Mutter über den Tod ihres Sohns informiert):

  > Weil ich es dir sage. Und mach es **chennet** aus. Ich will kein Geschrei. Versteht sich, Geschrei lieb ich nicht.

Ich habe "chennet" in keinem Wörterbuch finden können, z.B. in *DUDEN. Das große Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache in 10 Bänden* oder *Deutsches Wörterbuch von Jacob und Wilhelm Grimm*. Also, was bedeutet "chennet"?

Comment: So wie sich's anhört scheint es _sauber_, _sauber bleiben_ zu bedeuten. Evtl. ein französisches Modewort aus der Epoche (das Stück spielt im 19. Jhdt.). Eine befriedigende Übersetzung aus dem Französischen habe ich allerdings auch nicht gefunden.

Comment: chennet → *schön nett* (jiddische Aussprache?)

Comment: @Janka Ja, das hatte ich auch gedacht, aber die Schreibweise? _"Schee nett"_ wäre plausibler für mich.

Comment: Man muss glaube ich Linguist sein um mit dieser Quelle was anfangen zu können (deshalb keine Antwort), aber da wird das anscheinend erklärt: https://books.google.de/books?id=Kcy_D3HtY2AC&pg=PA441&lpg=PA441&dq=chennet

Answer (score 8):

Das Wort stammt aus dem Jiddischen und wahrscheinlich vom hebräischen "hen" (Schönheit, Gnade, Anmut) ab. Hat also mit dem deutschen "schön" nur wenig zu tun außer einer uralten Verwandtschaft und einer sehr ähnlichen Bedeutung.

Siehe [Westjiddisches Wörterbuch](https://books.google.de/books?id=Kcy_D3HtY2AC&pg=PA441&lpg=PA441&dq=chennet&source=bl&ots=DWXypEozEY&sig=nvBxvBTNCnpJ3t2V2FT8505Gbrw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiig9mN__jYAhWDy6QKHVmsBzo4ChDoAQg1MAI#v=onepage&q=chennet&f=false), S. 441ff

Comment: "uralte Verwandtschaft" ?